# How to communicate between Wordpress database and android application

Tags: android

please tell how can i access database of WordPress(make new tables and get data from tables)through android application please share any code example if any body have.

Comment: make webservice for that database table, fetch JSON/XML.

Comment: OR you can parse the RSS Feed (XML) wordpress provides for your posts/comments.

Comment: any example code link?

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress uses a mysql database. So you can do it in several different ways. I recommend you to write a bridge in php that gets the data from the database and sends it to your app JSON encoded.

For example, your php file could look something like this for retrieving data:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","db_user","db_password");
mysql_select_db("database_name");

if(isset($_REQUEST['getrecords']))
   getRecords($_REQUEST['id']);

function getRecords($id){
    $q=mysql_query("select * from test_ranking where id=$id");
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;
    print(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Of course this is very insecure and you should write some extra code to make this script fit your needs.
After doing this, you can simply make a httprequest from your android app and get the json data.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thats the thing i have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress provides an rss in xml. you have to parse it get data from wordpress site. You have to implement/specify the rss feeds.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend  soap 
I have never done it in  php but here is something  on php soap 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

and  for the android part
http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/   libraries
and
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2genstub/   proxy generator